# How To assign same value To Each element of array in react native. How to Make key pair array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, arraylist

I Have Array data Like this

```
Subcategories:["Wooden Furniture","Office Furniture","Kitchen Furniture","Modular Office Furniture","Industrial Furniture","Steel Furniture","Living Room Furniture","|Storage and Display Furniture","Entryway Furniture","Inflatable Furniture","Patio Furniture & Accessories","Storage and Display Furniture"," Office & Commercial Furniture "]
```

Now I want To Assign same Key To each Element In it. Basically I want To Make Key Pair Value.
please help . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map`.

```
const directories = Subcategories.map(sub => {
  return { your_keyname: sub }
})
```

Comment: wooo wooo wooo thank bro you made it